# cmd opens when not supposed to

Tags: c, windows, cmd

Okay so I've been trying to learn c for a while, and i just got a book (Programming Windows by Charles Petzold) And i just wrote my first program using code:blocks. Everything is working fine, but for some reason it opens the cmd window and if it it closes the program. here's the code

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int  
                   iCmdShow)
{
static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("HelloWin");
HWND         hwnd;
MSG          msg;
WNDCLASS     wndclass;

wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

if(!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
{
    MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This computer is stupid so im not gona work!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}
hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, TEXT ("The program"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                     NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT rect;

switch (message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
         MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("a sound would play but i dont have the cd"),    
TEXT("sound"), 0);
         return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
         hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);
         GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
         DrawText (hdc, TEXT("sup, bra."), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER
                           | DT_VCENTER);
         EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
         return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
         PostQuitMessage(0);
         return 0;
}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The DefWindowProc statement is misplaced. It should be moved to within the switch statement block, not as the return statement from WinMain.  WinMain should simply have a `return 0` statement as the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting the CONSOLE subsystem when you link. When you do so the result is an executable that automatically has a console when started.

Instead you need to target the GUI subsystem. A GUI subsystem executable is not automatically given a console window when it starts.

You will need to find the option in your IDE, or your link command line, that specifies the subsystem, and make the appropriate change.

Comment: It is a linker option, not compiler.  /SUBSYSTEM for Microsoft's link.exe

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I was using the term compiling loosly

Comment: How does one manage to compile a CONSOLE app without defining main()? Or does code-blocks use a different compiler?

Comment: @selbie I don't really know about Code::Blocks. For MSVC link.exe, use of WinMain only implies GUI subsystem if the subsystem is not explicitly specified.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - that's what I'm getting at. With the MS compiler, the program will simply not link if you target CONSOLE and only provide WinMain. I wonder if the op actually wrote a stub main or if code::blocks injects one for him (which would be odd.)

Comment: @selbie OK, I'm with you. Would seem quite likely that the compiler is not MSVC. I suspect mingw.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? MinGW?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I happened to have MingGW laying around on my disk. Oddly enough, "g++ winmain.cpp" with will produce a console exe and have WinMain as the entry point. Mystery solved.